# Create node with multiple image fields

Tags: services, media

I have a requirement to create a node with a REST API. I am using the  services module from which I am able to create node of any content type successfully. But here I have added new three image fields which contains upload field type.

With this services api, I want to create node with title body and upload 3 images as well from a HTML form.

How can I achieve this with API.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Patch the Services module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2224803) to allow for multiple items on a field
2. Use Services to create the file and get the file id
3. Use Services to save/update the node and place the file ids onto the image field

For steps 2 and 3, see [this blog post](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-services-file-create-example-json-and-jquery).